# How can I optimize my project for the linker in C++ Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, linker, mingw

I have a project that currently exists of a static library, an executable and a test executable. The two executables link to the static library. The static library contains almost all C++ and header files.

I am using Qt 5.14 and have defined around 3000 `Q_PROPERTY`s (3000 getter and 3000 setter functions). I have enabled -Wa,-mbig-obj as a compiler options because mocs_compilation.cpp was getting too big to compile. The project is currently compiled for Windows in Mingw with gcc.

My problem currently lies in the slow linking of the project. It takes a very long time for the linker to process the static library.

There are possibilities to switch compilers or linkers, but my interest is currently in the structure of the project. What does the linker like best?

- A lot of .cpp files and a lot of .o files?
- Or actually a big single .o file?
- Will it be faster when I do dynamic linking?
- Should I split my files into more libraries than just one?

I couldn't really find a source that gives me best practices for such a project.

Comment: `Will it be faster when I do dynamic linking?` Somewhat. You'll still pay the cost of linking in the DLL as you would in an EXE.  The only difference is that you only have that cost once (in the linking of DLL) instead of twice with the pair of EXE binaries.

Comment: Well, the two executables are actually quite ok during linking. It's really the processing of the static library by the linker that is slow.

Comment: **static libraries are not processed by the linker.**  They are just a concatenation of all the .o files returned by the compiler.  If it's the case, that the archive generation of the lib is taking too long, you could consider splitting it up into different libs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by process the static library?  I assume you mean some step after all the individual .cpp files are compiled.  Does your build output suggest which step this is?

Comment: The step in cmake is called `[59/274] Linking CXX static library src\liblibocsui.a
`. I will try to figure out the exact step with verbose cmake.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MinGW as I am with the Microsoft compiler, but this step is typically performed on linux with the `ar` tool.  Or the `lib` tool on Windows.